# Method overloading where and how meta data will be saved during compilation in java

Tags: java, overloading

How does it actually works during run time. If it is decided what to call during compilation time it self where all those meta data is stored. If at all it is stored in .class file itself how it is saved.

```
   public class Test {

    public void print(Number num) {
        System.out.println("Number");
    }

    public void print(Integer num) {
        System.out.println("Integer");
    }

    public void print(Long num) {
        System.out.println("Long");
    }

    public void print(Double num) {
        System.out.println("Double");
    }

    public void print(Float num) {
        System.out.println("Float");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test test = new Test();
        test.print(10);
        test.print(10.0);
    }

}
```

Result:

```
Integer
Double
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply because that is how literals in Java work; see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) for example.

If you provide a "whole" number; it is interpreted as Integer; unless you do something like `10L` to indicate: long.

For floating point numbers it is just the other way round; double is the default; and `10.1F` turns it into a float.

Comment: Java decides which method to call during complication time in case of overloading correct

Comment: Sure; that would be another of those basic facts documented all over the place.

Comment: Where and how those metadata will be saved during compilation and that will be used in during run time

Answer (score 0):

When you pass an argument, for e.g. 10, it would understand like it is int (default type for integers). Then it would search for a method which requires an int argument. But it would fail to find such a method. Then it would apply autoboxing, and would search for a method which requires Integer argument. If it would fail to do so, it would search for any super type of Integer. As we know Number is superclass of Integer, it would be satisfied with Number argument as well. But Long is not a superclass of Integer, that is, Long is not a covariant type of Integer, so it would not match which requires a Long argument.

Now let's come to the float value part.
double is the default type for floating point numbers. Means,

```
x = 4.0;
```

then x must be double.

```
float x = 4.0; //won't compile.
float x = 4.0f; //would compile.

double y = 4.0; //would compile.
```

This signifies, double is the default type for floating point numbers.

When you pass 10.0 it would look for a method which accepts double, if it fails to find such a method, it would look for a method which accepts Double.